# Show only 10 items using jquery infinite scroll within the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I found lots of examples related to this question, but so far the examples that I see they don't match my needs.On my div at the moment I load all the list content retrieved from my function,My goal is I want to be able to only show 6 items and keep on appending the other 6 until the list is exhausted using the infinite scroll in jQuery.
This is how my list look within the div.

```
<div class="listOfAnything">
    <div class="all">apple</div>
    <div class="all">Banana</div>
    <div class="all">Guava</div>
    <div class="all">Pear</div>
    <div class="all">mango</div>
    <div class="all">Grapes</div>
    <div class="all">Avocado</div>
    <div class="all">Orange</div>
    <div class="all">Lemon</div>
    <div class="all">Nartjie</div>
    <div class="all">Granadilla</div>
    <div class="all">pawpaw</div>
    <div class="all">Ginger</div>
    <div class="all">Watermelon</div>
    <div class="all">potato</div>
    <div class="all">Sweet Potato</div>
    <div class="all">Peach</div>
</div>
```

I've tried to follow the tutorials on http://scrollmagic.io/examples/advanced/infinite_scrolling.html but I had no luck because i got stuck here

```
function addBoxes (amount) {
    for (i=1; i<=amount; i++) {
        var randomColor = '#'+('00000'+  (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16)).slice(-6);
        $("<div></div>")
            .addClass("box1")
            .css("background-color", randomColor)
            .appendTo(".dynamicContent #content");
    }
    // "loading" done -> revert to normal state
    scene.update(); // make sure the scene gets the new   start position
    $("#loader").removeClass("active");
}

 // add some boxes to start with.
addBoxes(18);
```

Because I already have the content on my div.

Comment: What scene.update() does?

Comment: Getting the new start position

Comment: I do understand what the function does ,it actually make new box every time u scroll.But evrything is within the Js script and is happening when u scroll down ,of which on my case there is already a content loaded but i don't wanna show everything at the same time

Comment: you could create an array to store all the fruits then display by selecting the index from-to position e.g [0,5] [6,11] [12,17] etc -- 6  items  per. make sure the 1st 6 items are are larger than the page because you next to scroll pass them to show the next 6. like in the demo

Answer (score 0):

Added the scroll function

```
function addBoxes (amount) {
for (i=1; i<=amount; i++) {
    var randomColor = '#'+('00000'+  (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16)).slice(-6);
    $("<div></div>")
            .addClass("box1")
            .css("background-color", randomColor)
            .appendTo(".dynamicContent #content");
    }
    // "loading" done -> revert to normal state
    scene.update(); // make sure the scene gets the new   start position
    $("#loader").removeClass("active");
}

// add some boxes to start with.
addBoxes(6);

// do things on mousescroll
$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event)
{
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0 || event.originalEvent.detail > 0) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            addBoxes(6);
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have that part.  also.

Comment: so if u wanna show some boxes with delay use:  setTimeout(addBoxes, 1000, 9); where 1000 is 1 second delay

Comment: Let me just simply say on my div <div class="listOfAnything"> there are more than 6 items show on the page ,my goal is to show 6 and keep on adding 6 when the user is scrolling to the bottom of the page.

Comment: edited.. if you need to do it just 1 time, add a var and check for it inside mousewheel event